# How to set current sequence while converting primary key serial(integer) to bigserial(bigint)

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, table, auto-increment, sequence

The table already has few thousands of rows and I want to convert the primary key from Integer to BigInteger. How to change the sequence for biginteger?

```
--Create new temp sequence (sequence-name1) for bigint
CREATE SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq1
    INCREMENT 1
    START 5542
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq1  OWNER TO postgres;
--Alter column to bigint
ALTER TABLE public.case_audit ALTER COLUMN case_audit_uid TYPE bigint;  
--Alter pk column with temp Sequence
ALTER TABLE public.case_audit ALTER COLUMN case_audit_uid SET DEFAULT     nextval('indsolv.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq1'::regclass);
--Drop original sequence
DROP SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq;
--Create new sequence for bigint with original sequence name
CREATE SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 5542
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq OWNER TO postgres;
---Set original sequence
ALTER TABLE public.case_audit ALTER COLUMN case_audit_uid SET DEFAULT nextval('public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq'::regclass);
---Drop temp sequence
DROP SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq1;
```

Is there any simple solution compare to this?

Comment: You don't need to change the sequence. It generates `bigint` values anyway. All you need to do is change the _column_ to `bigint`

Comment: No, I am getting an "ERROR:  nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq" (2147483647)"

Comment: Then you must have explicitly defined it as an integer sequence, because the default is `bigint`

Comment: Yes, I have used EA Sparx System for data modeling and to generate DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PgAdmin4 has no option to modify graphically but as per [PostgreSQL Document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html), we can alter the sequence data type to smallint, integer, and bigint

Alter table column & sequence data type and set max value for the sequence

```
ALTER SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq AS bigint;
ALTER SEQUENCE public.case_audit_case_audit_uid_seq MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807;
ALTER TABLE public.case_audit ALTER COLUMN case_audit_uid TYPE bigint;
```